# addEventListener Created an Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I added an event listener and it created an infinite loop I really don't get what I did wrong.

What happen is it keeps clicking the images by itself

Here's my code:

```
function attachOnClickEvent(cases,theme,debut,capture){
    var images=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        images[i].addEventListener("click",x(cases,theme,debut,capture),false);
    }
};

var x=function(cases,theme,debut,capture){newImage(this,cases,theme,debut,capture);};

function newImage(elem,cases,theme,debut,capture){
    var images=preloadImages(cases,theme);
    var imgTab=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var Id=elem.id;
    elem.src=images[randomTab[Id]];

};
```

Hope someone can find my mistake.. Thanks!

Comment: I see 3 function declarations here but no calls to the functions. Can you post a more complete code example? Specifically, please post your HTML and show your event bindings.

Comment: Better yet, make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

1. `getElementsByTagName` is returning a live *NodeList*
2. You are invoking your *function* `x` each time instead of adding it as a handler
3. A new `<img>` is created
4. the *NodeList* has it's length increased by `1`
5. The next iteration is the same distance away from the end as the previous one

There are two things you need to consider, firstly as I mention in `2`, you're invoking `x` when you aren't meaning to. Secondly, you may avoid some problems with live lists by looping downwards

---

One fix to get your desired result may be to rewrite `attachOnClickEvent` like this

```
function attachOnClickEvent(cases, theme, debut, capture) {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        handler = function (e) {
            return x(cases, theme, debut, capture);
        },
        i;
    for (i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        images[i].addEventListener("click", handler, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I do instead to add x as an handler? Also the images are created before with another function

Comment: Because you're trying to pass your parameters through, you'll need to create a new closure over them (i.e. a function) which wraps `x`, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

One issue would seem to be that you are not using callbacks properly.

Callbacks need to be function objects and cannot be returned as you are intending.

```
function (cases, theme, debut, capture) {
    return function() { newImage(this, cases, theme, debut, capture); };
}
```

Try returning an anonymous function.

Comment: Hey when I return an anonymous function it works however I need to delete some of these events down the road so I cant work only with anonymous functions...

Comment: Then attach your parameters to the image element and you can use `this` to access them again

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that.. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to see how you're calling these functions, but I noticed that on this line:

```
images[i].addEventListener("click",x(cases,theme,debut,capture),false);
```

You are calling your function `x`, rather than assigning it as the event listener. Since that function adds an image to the page, the loop never completes, since it iterates through all images on the page. This line should instead be:

```
images[i].addEventListener("click", x , false );
```